# How to send a html page from java

Tags: java, html, upload

I have this form into an html page:

```
<form name="form1" id="form1" action="test" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="hiddenfield1" value="ok">
    File to upload:
    <input type="file" size="50" name="file3">
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

I want to send a file to this page calling it from java and passing the file path through my client.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You need a library like [Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/) which implements part of the web browser that fills out forms (and especially the "upload files" part).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need server-side Java. I suggest looking into Java Servlets. That is one way to accomplish this.